# JSP being compiled in Java 8 on app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to use the push to deploy feature on app engine. The Jenkins build job successfully deploys the was file on app engine.

But when I access the jsp on appspot.com I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/guestbook_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

The `jenkins` command to deploy:

```
gcloud --project=<project-id> preview app deploy target/guestbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The above errors I guess suggests that the JSP is compiled in Java 8 but the JRE is Java 7.

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong here?

I am using a Java Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It is avoided by having  a separate installation of jdk 7, but not like that idea. I prefer to find a proper solution.

setting the source and target to 1.7 in the maven org.apache.maven.plugins plugging does not solve the problem. My source code gets compile to 1.7, but the JSPs codes is compile to 1.8.

there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not compiled on App Engine as the title states but on your computer. You're using Java 8 to compile the source code, that's why you see the `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` exception message.

Compile the code with Java 7. You can check which Java do you have e.g. for Linux:

```
java -version
```

You can try to set `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable to Java 7 home directory, then open a new terminal or relogin.

Comment: I am not compiling the source on my machine. The source code is checked pushed to google app engine project using Git. And then I have a Jenkins setup on Google Compute Engine VM which builds and deploys the code. I have checked the Java version on the VM and it is 1.7

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [Java compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to Java version 1.7:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: yes, i already have this in my pom file. I have followed every step mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy. I am not compiling my source on my local environment. The code is pushed to app engine project git repository and the Jenkins instance on compute engine is setup to build and deploy the code to app engine. I have checked the java version on the compute engine vm and it is 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with push-to-deploy. When you login to the instance and do a java -version, you see that it is Java7, but that is not the java used by the docker image cloud-dev-java that is used to build your project with jenkins. If you add a build step for the shell and execute java -version there you will see, that this image uses openjdk-8.

I fixed this by installing Java7 by hand in the docker image. Here is how I fixed this in detail:

- Login to the Cloud instance (bitnami-jenkins) via SSH from the cloud console
- check the names of the running docker instances

  mpoehler_gmail_com@bitnami-jenkins:~$ sudo docker ps
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                   COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
  548bc88db321        container.cloud.google.com/_b_dev_containers/cloud-dev-go:prod       "/bin/bash /google/s   27 hours ago        Up 27 hours                             condescending_kowalevski
  d9fe6779f5d9        container.cloud.google.com/_b_dev_containers/cloud-dev-php:prod      "/bin/bash /google/s   27 hours ago        Up 27 hours                             hungry_turing
  **aedb0573a460        container.cloud.google.com/_b_dev_containers/cloud-dev-java:prod     "/bin/bash /google/s   27 hours ago        Up 27 hours                             mad_kowalevski**
  bef5657ea109        container.cloud.google.com/_b_dev_containers/cloud-dev-python:prod   "/bin/bash /google/s   27 hours ago        Up 27 hours                             reverent_bohr
- we are looking for the **cloud-dev-java** container with the name **mad_kowalevski**
- now install java 7 in that container:

  sudo docker exec mad_kowalevski sudo apt-get update

  sudo docker exec mad_kowalevski sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk
- after that run java -version to see if it works as expected

  sudo docker exec mad_kowalevski java -version

  - should result in

  java version "1.7.0_79"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-1~deb8u1)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

And after that the build will work as expected.